# Run usdz_converter but nothing come out

Tags: xcode, usdz

I tried to run command

xcrun usdz_converter test_obj.obj test_obj.usdz

command is successfully run and it said converted, but no any new file generated.

Anyone facing same problem ?

USING XCODE 10A255 OS High Sierra Version 10.13.6

[result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCpxe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I solved it by updating Xcode to the current Beta version 10.1. After that open xcode go to

Preferences -> Locations

Set the command line tools to the new beta xcode version.

Now the USDZ conversion should work